# Can I get a templated uniform distribution generator which will work for any numeric type?

Tags: c++, templates, random, std

Question says it all. I want something like this:

```
template <typename T> 
void foo() {
    std::cout << "A random number: " << UniformDistribution<T>.get();
}
```

which works for at least the following types: number (integers/floating-point, signed/unsigned and real/complex); enums; booleans. I know about [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) and [std::uniform_real_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) - I want something more generally templated.

Comment: You could try specializing a wrapper with predicates like `is_integral`, `is_floating_point`, etc... This would work as long as it is used with built-in types only.

Answer (score 1):

`uniform_int_distribution` and `uniform_real_distribution` behave differently; the former distributes on `[a, b]` for parameters *a*, *b* while the latter distributes on `[a, b)`. Also, the default parameter values are different; `0, numeric_limits<>::max()` for the former and `0, 1` for the latter.

Once you've decided which behaviour you're interested in you can write it yourself; it wouldn't make sense for such a distribution to be part of the standard.

Comment: I realize these two are not the same. I'm asking if there's something that's standard / popular that people use. Not just for int's and float's - also for bools, enums etc.